# Plugin GameCenterUI.GameCenterDashboardExtension invalidated

Tags: swift, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

```
 plugin com.apple.GameCenterUI.GameCenterDashboardExtension invalidated
```

I'm trying to get a simple high score system working in my game. I've followed all the tutorials online, and here is what I have right now.

When the user opens the app, I run this code (InitialViewController)

```
//initiate gamecenter
    func authenticateLocalPlayer(){

        let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()

        localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(viewController, error) -> Void in

            if (viewController != nil) {
                self.presentViewController(viewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

            else {
                print((GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated))
            }
        }

    }
```

Then, after the user finishes their game, I report their score to Game Center using this function

```
//send high score to leaderboard
    func saveHighscore(score:Int) {

        // if player is logged in to GC, then report the score
        if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated {
            let gkScore = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: "ID_THAT_I_DOUBLE_CHECKED_MANY_TIMES")
            gkScore.value = Int64(score)

            GKScore.reportScores([gkScore], withCompletionHandler: { (error: NSError?) in
                if (error != nil) {
                    // handle error
                    print("Error: " + error!.localizedDescription);
                } else {
                    print("Score reported: \(gkScore.value)")
                }
            })

        }
    }
```

**(I usually get the error here)**

Not sure if this is important, but here is how i open the leaderboard and close it

```
//shows leaderboard screen
    func showLeader() {
        let vc = self
        let gc = GKGameCenterViewController()
        gc.gameCenterDelegate = self
        vc.presentViewController(gc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    //hides leaderboard screen
    func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController) {
        gameCenterViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

If I can be anymore specific, please comment below, I'm waiting by the computer.

Stack Overflows I've already refrenced

- [GameCenter not updating leaderboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978447/gamecenter-not-updating-leaderboard)
- [Swift - Integrate GameCenter to use leaderboards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25291731/swift-integrate-gamecenter-to-use-leaderboards)

Here is the only output I see on the leaderboard:

[image: Output]

**Is there an alternative way to do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same exact code for the leaderboards, and the same exact error. It was working fine for me over a week ago, and just recently I got the same error. I'm guessing the issue is on Apple's end. There might be a bug in Game Center at the moment. Hopefully it'll get fixed. Eventually.

Comment: So there's nothing we can do huh

Comment: @RonakShah Yeah, I guess not. At least not at the moment.

Comment: I realized it doesn't give that error when you try it on an iOS 8.1 simulator. Try to see if you're able to update the leaderboards now on that version.

Comment: the problem is im using UIStackView, so I have to use ios 9 :(

Comment: @RonakShah Do you mean wait for the score to update?

Comment: Yeah I my score goes through to the Leaderboard now

Comment: @RonakShah Awesome! Too bad it's not working for me. Maybe it's because I have multiple leaderboards.